# Resize paths generated by PaintCode

Tags: svg, uiview, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I'm using [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/) to convert a set of SVGs I have to use in to Swift code. It looks like it just converts the SVG paths in to `UIBezierPath()`s, which is great.

To display the generated code I'm doing the following:

```
class FirstImageView: UIView {

    init(name: String) { // Irrelevant custom init
        super.init(frame: CGRectMake(15, 15, 40, 40)) // 40x40 View
        self.opaque = false // Transparent background
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        ImagesCollection.firstImage() // Fill the view with this image
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Where `ImagesCollection.firstImage()` is referencing:

```
public class ImagesCollection: NSObject {

    public class func firstImage() {
        let color4 = UIColor(red: 0.595, green: 0.080, blue: 0.125, alpha: 1.000)
        var fill295Path = UIBezierPath()
        fill295Path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(27.5, 2.73))
        // Rest of generated graphics code
    }

}
```

Which works great - I generated the graphics at 40x40, set the frame to 40x40, and that works fine. What I'm wondering now, is how can I display that same graphic at a smaller (or larger size) - since they're bezier paths they should scale fine, right? Setting my View's frame to `CGRectMake(15, 15, 20, 20)` (for a desired 20x20 image) just seems to clip the graphic.

How can I ensure that whatever graphic is drawn in to my View is sized to the view's frame?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CGAffineTransform` to scale either your custom view or the bezier path itself.

1. Scale the view:

   ```
   myFirstImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5)
   ```
2. Scale the bezier path:

   ```
   // ...
   // lots of generated graphics code
   fill295Path.applyTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5))
   fill295Path.stroke() // or fill, etc.
   ```

Comment: I actually ended up using SVGKit to load in my SVGs as Core Graphics, but your answer is still correct so thank you! All booty for you sir!

Comment: Woohoo! It would be great to see an answer about how to do what you did using SVGKit - you could ask/answer yourself, or post another answer here.

Comment: I'm sure I could do that! I'll post it as an additional answer here by EOD :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you generated the code with PaintCode, you could draw their Frame object around your SVG/Bezier. It would generate the Bezier with dynamic size. In your example, you would get `ImagesCollection.firstImage(#frame: CGRect)` instead of `ImagesCollection.firstImage()`. You just pass the rectangle from `drawRect` to it and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off-topic, but per Nate's request here's how I did it with SVGKit:

- Firstly, you'll want to incorporate SVGKit in your project by following [these](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit#build-the-static-library-automatic) instructions
- With the markup in your SVG file, parse the SVG data using the SVGKParser:

`let svgData: String = "<svg>...</svg>"`

`let svgParse: SVGKParser = SVGKParser(source: SVGKSource(inputSteam: NSInputStream(data: svgData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!)))`

`svgParse.addDefaultSVGParserExtensions()`

- From there you'll load it into an image, using the SVGKImage type:

`var svgImage: SVGKImage = SVGKImage(parsedSVG: svgResult, fromSource: nil)`

- And lastly, you can use it as the image in an SVGKFastImageView:

`SVGKFastImageView(SVGKImage: svgImage)`